# is it possible to render as pdf with font Actor

Tags: apex, visualforce, renderas, font

I tried the following to render a custom font in visual force

```
<apex:stylesheet value="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Actor"/>

.cal {
    font-family: 'Actor';
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  #content { font-family: Actor; !important }
```

This seems to work without the render as pdf. Is there a way to use custom fonts in the render as pdf. I also tried with fonts in the static recource but this didnt work eighter.

Comment: As far as I can tell, no, you can't use custom fonts in PDF mode. You're limited solely to the available fonts defined by the system. I'd love to be proven wrong, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible.

> ## [Fonts Available When Using Visualforce PDF Rendering](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm)
>
> Visualforce PDF rendering supports a limited set of fonts. To ensure that PDF output renders as you expect, use the supported font names.
>
> For each typeface, the first font-family name listed is recommended.
>
> ```
> Typeface            font-family Values
> ---------------------------------------
> Arial Unicode MS    - Arial Unicode MS
> ---------------------------------------
> Helvetica           - sans-serif
>                     - SansSerif
>                     - Dialog
> ---------------------------------------
> Times               - serif
>                     - Times
> ---------------------------------------
> Courier             - monospace
>                     - Courier
>                     - Monospaced
>                     - DialogInput
> ```